# US state (or other country) with sub-16 driver's license?

Tags: driving-license, paperwork

In many (most?) states in the USA, people can drive alone legally at age **16**.

(Typically at 15 they can drive under supervision of an adult driver, and then on the 16th birthday can pass a test so as to drive fully alone.)

i) is there a US state where the drive-alone age is younger than 16?

(**Setting aside** "hardship" licenses: in some eg. rural areas people can get a driver's license before 16 if especially needed because of, eg., medical issues etc.)

ii) indeed, setting aside the US, is there a 1st or 2nd world country where, again, one can get a license to drive (alone) younger than 16?

I really couldn't find a "list of driver's license ages" on a worldwide basis, nor on an intra-US basis.

Comment: What's the expats link / relevance for this question?

Comment: hey bud .. huh? establishing a driver's license is an expat basic.

Comment: Are you planning to move somewhere based solely on where you / your kids can get a driving license the earliest? Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia articles, as Joe Blow notes, have enough information to answer the question.

In addition to "hardship" licenses, there is a more common distinction between "restricted" or "provisional" licenses and full licenses.  The limitations of provisional licenses vary by state; they typically comprise some combination of the following:

- restrictions against driving at night
- restrictions against carrying passengers, which may be based on the number of passengers or their age
- probationary rules that delay the acquisition of a full license if the driver commits any violations while holding the restricted license

According to the list, no US state offers a full license to drivers younger than 16 years old.  The following states offer restricted licenses to younger drivers:

- 15 years, 6 months

  - New Mexico
  - South Carolina
  - Wisconsin
- 15 years

  - Idaho
  - Kansas
  - Montana
  - North Dakota
- 14 years, 6 months

  - South Dakota (reduced to 14 years, 3 months after completion of a driver's education course)

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driver%27s_license_in_the_United_States

In addition to the US states noted above, the following jurisdictions permit drivers younger 16 years old to drive without supervision:

- El Salvador (15 years)
- Malaysia (15 years for "light vehicles" and "commercial vehicles")
- Sweden (15 years for "EPA-Traktors")

The Wikipedia page lists the minimum age in the Northern Mariana Islands as "15/16", but this appears to be a misreading of the [cited source](http://www.ghsa.org/html/stateinfo/bystate/nmi.html), which gives "15/6" (that is, 15 years, 6 months) as the minimum age for a learner's permit, and reports "no data" for other stages and restrictions of the jurisdiction's graduated licensing scheme.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_minimum_driving_age

Comment: superb answer..

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I found the question well-answered by these lists:

[international](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_minimum_driving_age)

[intra-USA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driver%27s_license_in_the_United_States#Licenses_for_adults_and_minors.3B_GDL_laws)

Essentially, South Dakota (the USA state) has, I believe, the lowest-age for legal driving.